# "Companies will increase their capacity" or "capacities"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> Companies will increase their production **capacity** in 2017.
>
> Companies will increase their production **capacities** in 2017.

A Google search shows that "capacity" is more common. But I wonder, would it be correct to use the plural form, considering that each company has a different capacity?

Answer (score 1):

The singular is correct

> production capacity

is the name of an operating item.  Consider

> Companies will increase their **headcount**.
>   Companies will increase their **investment spending**.
>   Companies will increase their **parking lot size**.

in none of these similar examples would the plural be used.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the singular form is correct? I realized that I should use the singular form but was not sure about the reason behind it.

Comment: A company's "production capacity" without further context is the aggregate capacity, of which there is only one.

Comment: But there are several companies here and each company has a different capacity. Why is it not necessary to use "capacities" to highlight that fact?

Comment: The sentence would be understood to be "*(Each of the)* companies will increase their *(individual)* production capacity in 2017."

Answer (score 1):

You can use **capacities** if there is something countable about what the speaker is trying to express.

> Acme will increase their capacities at 3 factories to meet seasonal demand.

Though using the singular expresses nearly the exact same thing.